# Uploading file using HTML

Tags: html, file-upload

Can anyone show me how to create an HTML page that allows to upload files?
It will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File uploads cannot be done purely in HTML. You must have some kind of server logic to process the Multipart-data from the HTML-form (by using ASP.Net, PHP or whatever).

Comment: here's one way to do it: http://www.dotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/FileUpload06072007061316AM/FileUpload.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in pure HTML, you need a script on server side to store the file.

If you can use PHP, check the [manual on handling file uploads for details](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html

You would need some server side componenet ot store the uploaded content for you.
There are near to infinite options for that. :)
Also, you have styled File uplaod components provided by various Ajax libraries and Tool kits like [DOJO](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/09/02/the-dojo-toolkit-multi-file-uploader/) ,[jQuery](http://www.uploadify.com/) that make it look more nice and provide various flavors to do this.